# CSS Lazy Loading in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I've ran into some weird cases of positioning problems when lazy loading CSS in Chrome, e.g. the positioning of some elements (absolute, relative and cascaded) is off by sometimes huge margin.

Basically what I'm doing is leaving out the standard loading of the stylesheet via an link-Tag and instead placing a placeholder span-Tag for the sake of having an easy way to retrieve the URL later on at the end of the body-Tag. After the DOM loaded fully, I replace the span-Tag with a generated link-Tag like this:

```
loadCSS: function()
{
    var el = jQuery('.is_css');
    if(!el.length) return;

    // Build link element
    var linkEl = jQuery('<link />').attr({
        media: 'all',
        type: 'text/css',
        rel: 'stylesheet',
        href: el.data('src')
    });

    el.replaceWith(linkEl);
}
```

I can verify that the CSS is fully loaded as most of the elements are looking exactly as if I embed the CSS directly in the head-Tag. My guess is that Chrome doesn't correctly calculate positions in some circumstances for absolute or relative positioned elements when the CSS is loaded after the DOM has been loaded.

I would like to provide you with HTML / CSS Snippets, unfortunately it's out of scope to isolate the falsely rendered Elements. So instead I'm asking if anybody encountered similar problems that can cause this behaviour. Maybe there are some general hints on how to fix such problems.

Kind regards

Comment: are you lazy loading all your CSS or just additional chunks?

Comment: Have you looked at this: https://github.com/rgrove/lazyload -- it's no longer being updated or maintained but it might either provide a solution or a base for you to create your own version.

Comment: What happens if you force repaint **after** CSS was loaded? [repaint snippet](http://pastebin.com/V4YverjY)

Comment: @diggersworld: I'm loading the full CSS, no chunks.

Comment: @BogdanKuštan: Same result - positioning is off after the repaint also

Comment: @Sutuma: can I ask why you're doing it? It might be your taking performance too far. One thing to note is that if you lazy load all your CSS then there will be a period of time that the page is completely unstyled, and from a user perspective that's not going to look very good.

Comment: How many `<span class="is_css">` do you have?

Comment: What diggersworld said. This makes no sense.

Comment: If you're that concerned with optimizing initial load, you might wanna look into inlining your *above-the-fold* styles, then lazy-load in the rest

Comment: Regardless if the approach to performance makes sense or not, this ultimately concerns "dynamically loaded CSS". These files should always parse and apply correctly. There are many places where people use dynamically loaded CSS, like in AJAX-based apps. If there is a bug/limitation/gotcha somewhere, we ought to find out why. Let's not sweep the question under the carpet just yet.

Comment: @monners Thats exactly what I'm doing.

Comment: @light There is only one element that is being replaced.

Answer (score 3):

Sutuma,

The methodology you are trying could have strong performance impact. 
As a principle CSS need to be loaded before html DOM is rendered to have an effect. My guess is your html is rendered before CSS get loaded.
Here are the option you may try:
1. Load all css in html header tag 
2. Reload your html page  one css is content is downloaded.
3. You can use html templating with (require js + require css plugin) for lazy loading.

[require js](http://requirejs.org/) , 
[require-css plugin](https://github.com/guybedford/require-css)